# Uploading images and multiple files in binary data format to SQL Server using ASP.NET with AngularJs

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload images and multiple files in binary data format to SQL Server using ASP.NET with AngularJs, I would be very grateful if you could help me how to do it.

Below is my home controller and my html page with my controller page that I wrote

```js
$scope.Add = function() {
    var _Employee = {

      "Image": $scope.img,
      "CV": $scope.CV
    };
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/Home/employeeCreate',
      data: _Employee
    })
```

```css
public JsonResult employeeCreate(Models.Employee _employee)
{
    try
    {          
        db.Employee.Add(_employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return GetEmployee();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
  <div class="profile-images-card">
    <div class="profile-images">
      <img src="../../img/profile1.jpg" id="upload-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
      <label for="fileupload">Fotograf Yükle</label>
      <input type="file" id="fileupload" ng-model="img" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="formFile" class="form-label">CV</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" ng-model="CV" />
  </div>
  <br /> <br />
  <div style="float:right">
    <input class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm" type="button" value="Temizle" ng-click="clearPersonnel()" />
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-sm" type="button" id="add" value="Kaydet" ng-click="Add(myform.$valid)" />
  </div>
</div>
```